# Pandas-iterate through a dataframe concatenating row values and column values into a new dataframe with respect to a specific column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a data-frame of 32250 rows x 901 columns :[image: data]
 I want to iterate throughout the row values of column 'TRAINSET' and concatenate respective row value of columns **'1','2','3'...n** and keep 'date' as the same for the concatenated field:

**for example**

```
 d= {     'TS': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
       'date':  [ 7,   6,   8 ],
         'X':   ['x', 'x', 'x'],
         'Y':   ['y', 'y', 'y']
     }
```

, i.e after operation, the resultant dataframe will look like this

```
d= {   'TS+1':  ['ax','ay','bx','by','cx','cy'],
       'date':  [ 7,   7,   6,   6,    8,   8 ],
         'X':   ['x', 'x',  'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
         'Y':   ['y', 'y',  'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']
    }
```

column **x,y....n** contains 32250 entries of the same value
**please check the image for actual data description**

The first few values of the resultant table will be like

```
d= { 'TRAINSET':['TNST175TC101','TNST175TC102','TNST175TC103','TNST175TC104','TNST175TC105'],
   'date':[ '2018-1-5','2018-1-5','2018-1-5','2018-1-5','2018-1-5'],
     '1':   ['TC101', 'TC101',  'TC101', 'TC101', 'TC101'],
     '2':   ['TC102', 'TC102',  'TC102', 'TC102', 'TC102']
        }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So, there won't be any az, bz, cz terms at all? Are you sure you have given the desired output?

Comment: Also, the output is not a consistent data frame because the length of the third column is not equal to the length of the other columns. I'd advise editing your post to reflect the answer to the question above as well as changing the output to be a consistent dataframe. It will help folks answer better. :)

Comment: the actual data-frame is pretty huge and this was my attempt at simplifying the problem. there are 900 columns with values: x,y,x,p,q,r...

Comment: I get that. But still ... let us stick to the same input and output for now. The output is not a real dataframe. An attempt to do a `pandas.DataFrame(d)` on the output won't work. So, you need to add three more values for key 'X'. 

And further you need to clarify - even in this mock example - if az, bz and cz should be in the output or not. My suspicion is that you missed them out when giving the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with add new values to `TS` columns by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and create default `RangeIndex` by `reset_index`:

```
df = pd.concat([df.assign(TS = df['TS'] + 'x'), 
                df.assign(TS = df['TS'] + 'y')]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   TS  date  X
0  ax     7  x
1  ay     7  x
2  bx     6  y
3  by     6  y
4  cx     8  z
5  cy     8  z
```

Comment: but , The actual problem does not contain just columns 'x' and 'y' but  900 columns with values ranging from TC101 - TC999. please check the image

Comment: if you increase the 'X' column , the concatenated column will increase in this order

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - Can you change data sample? Not sure if understand.

Comment: sure.note that cell values of columns 1-899 are the same , ie [TC101,TC102,TC103...TC999]